# River red gum seedlings developing new leaves at stem sign of stress?

Tags: seedlings

I am growing river red gums (eucalyptus camaldulensis) from seeds. They are now about two months old and approximately 10cm (4 inches) tall.

After only growing in one direction, they have suddenly both started developing new leaves at the stems of the existing leaves. Is this a sign of stress? Should I change something?

[image: Two eucalyptus seedlings]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.